# Is it possible to call ansible or ansible-playbook directly on a target host using a script or ansible itself?

Tags: windows, ansible, configuration-management

I need to know if it's possible to call / execute ansible playbooks from the target machine. I think i saw a vendor do it or at least something similar. they downloaded a script and it did ran the playbook.

if this is possible how would it be done?

my goal is to run ansible as a centralized server in aws to perform tasks in mulitple environments. most are behind firewalls, any reccomendations/thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If your host will install Ansible on target and feed it with all the playbooks the you can run it as any other executable. Should you do that is another story but technically there's no obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

You can run ansible and ansible playbook as you would any other binary on the target's $PATH, so any tool that facilitates running remote commands would work.

Because you are in AWS, one way might be to use [AWS System's Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

If you wanted to use Ansible itself to do this you could use the `shell` or `command` modules:

```
- hosts: target
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: ansible in ansible
    command: ansible --version

  - name: ansible-playbook in ansible
    command: ansible-playbook --version
```

Though, as with any situation where you reach for the `shell` or `command` modules, you have to be vigilant to maintain playbook idempotency yourself.

If you're requirement is just the ability to execute Ansible commands remotely, you might look into [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) which is the upstream project for Red Hat's [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/products/tower). It wraps ansible in a nice user interface to allow you to trigger Ansible playbooks remotely and with nice-to-haves like RBAC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with executing tasks remotely over ssh take a look at [Sparrowdo](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowdo) it has out of the box facilities to run bash scripts ( read ansible executable ) remotely from one master host to another. Or you can even use it to install all the ansible dependencies or whatever you need to do for your scope.